# using same button for back

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some javascript/CSS that hid/show content and some animation. It all works marvelously with no issues as far as functionality, however, I want to add a feature where the same picture/button that I click to run the script can again be used to run the same script in reverse to go back to the original state. See code below.

```
/* Portfolio */

    .portfolio {
      grid-area: portfolio;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .portfolio {
        display: grid;
        background: #F1F1F1;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 100%);
        grid-gap: 10px;
         grid-template-areas: "portfolio-header";
        align-items: start;
        text-align: center;
        min-height: 1000px; 
    }

    .portfolio-header {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 64px;
        margin-bottom: -300px;

    }

    .portfolio-container {
        min-height: 500px; /* temporary */
        padding: 0 20px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .portfolio-container .portfolio-picture {
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        transition: all ease-in .3s; /* MAGIC */
        top: 0;
        width: 25%;
    }
    .portfolio-container .portfolio-picture img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .portfolio-container .portfolio-picture.portfolio-picture-1 {}
    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-2 .portfolio-picture-1,
    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-3 .portfolio-picture-1,
    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-4 .portfolio-picture-1,
    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-1 .portfolio-picture-2,
    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-3 .portfolio-picture-2,
    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-4 .portfolio-picture-2,
    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-1 .portfolio-picture-3,
    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-2 .portfolio-picture-3,
    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-4 .portfolio-picture-3,
    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-1 .portfolio-picture-4,
    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-2 .portfolio-picture-4,
    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-3 .portfolio-picture-4 {
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;

    }
    .portfolio-container .portfolio-picture.portfolio-picture-2 { transform: translate(100%,0); }
    .portfolio-container .portfolio-picture.portfolio-picture-3 { transform: translate(200%,0); }
    .portfolio-container .portfolio-picture.portfolio-picture-4 { transform: translate(300%,0); }
    .portfolio-container .portfolio-content {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        opacity: 0;
        padding-left: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        transform: translate(0,100%);
        transition: all ease-in .3s; /* MAGIC */
        width: 75%;

    }

    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-2 .portfolio-picture.portfolio-picture-2,
    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-3 .portfolio-picture.portfolio-picture-3,
    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-4 .portfolio-picture.portfolio-picture-4 {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }


    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-1 .portfolio-content.portfolio-content-1,
    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-2 .portfolio-content.portfolio-content-2,
    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-3 .portfolio-content.portfolio-content-3,
    .portfolio-container.portfolio-active-4 .portfolio-content.portfolio-content-4 {
        opacity: 1;
        pointer-events: auto;
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }

    .portfolio-back-button { 
        display: none; 
    }
    .portfolio-back-button.portfolio-back-button-visible { 
        display: inline-block; 
    }

    .port-content {
        text-align: center;
    }


    .port-cont {
        max-width: 35%;
        text-align: justify;
        background-image: url("assets/img/pattern.png");
        color: #808080;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin-right: 40%;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        box-sizing: border-box;

    }

    function clearSelection() {
    document.querySelector('.portfolio-container').classList.remove('portfolio-active-1', 'portfolio-active-2', 'portfolio-active-3', 'portfolio-active-4');
    document.querySelector('.portfolio-back-button').classList.remove('portfolio-back-button-visible');
}
function selectPortfolio(which) {
    clearSelection();
    document.querySelector('.portfolio-container').classList.add('portfolio-active-' + which);
    document.querySelector('.portfolio-back-button').classList.add('portfolio-back-button-visible');
}

     <div  class="portfolio-container">

          <div class="portfolio-content portfolio-content-1 port-cont">
              <p>some text</p>
          </div>

          <div class="portfolio-content portfolio-content-2 port-cont">      
            <p>some text</p>
          </div>

          <div class="portfolio-content portfolio-content-3 port-cont">
            <p>some text</p>
          </div>

          <div class="portfolio-content portfolio-content-4 port-cont">
            <p>some text</p>
          </div>

          <div class="portfolio-picture portfolio-picture-1">
            <a href="#porfolio" onclick="selectPortfolio(1)"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/corinthmc/corinthmc_small.png" alt="Corinth Designs"></a>
          </div>

          <div class="portfolio-picture portfolio-picture-2">
            <a href="#porfolio" onclick="selectPortfolio(2)"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/beardedrazorback/beardedrazorback_small.png" alt="Corinth Designs"></a>
          </div>

          <div class="portfolio-picture portfolio-picture-3">
            <a href="#porfolio" onclick="selectPortfolio(3)"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/theord/theord_small.png" alt="Corinth Designs"></a>
          </div>

          <div class="portfolio-picture portfolio-picture-4">
            <a href="#porfolio" onclick="selectPortfolio(4)"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/21divine/21divine_small.png" alt="Corinth Designs"></a>
          </div>

            <div class="port-back portfolio-back-button">
            <a href="#work" onclick="clearSelection()">Back <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
          </div><!-- back button -->
```

Comment: you could add/switch between classes of the element via javascript, and then have the different css logic applied to those classes. That'll probably be the super easy way of doing it. Then do if(y class) remove y class and add x class else if(x class remove x class and add y class.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good idea. Appreciate it. I will get back if I have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the `selectPortfolio` function to the following, you can use a closure and an internal state variable to switch back and forth.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKbjQj?editors=0010

```
const selectPortfolio = (() => {
  let back = false;

  return (which) => {
    // clearSelection();

    if (back) {
      // document.querySelector('.portfolio-back-button').classList.add('portfolio-back-button-visible');
      console.log(back, 'portfolio-back-button-visible');
    } else {
      // document.querySelector('.portfolio-container').classList.add('portfolio-active-' + which);
      console.log(back, 'portfolio-active-');
    }

    back = !back;
  }    

  return back;
})();

selectPortfolio();
selectPortfolio();
selectPortfolio();
selectPortfolio();

// true "portfolio-back-button-visible"
// false "portfolio-active-"
// true "portfolio-back-button-visible"
// false "portfolio-active-"
```